# is it normal for a usb device o reset when windows enummerates the device

Tags: usb

I have brought myself a prusa I3 clone(3d printer).

I had my 3d printer printing directly from sd card however I switched on my pc to research something then the printer restarted itself when windows booted up. Am assuming its because windows emmerated the usb device? It has a ft232rl serial interface.

Is this normal?

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening again? There potential I could of lost hours of printing. It so happenes I'd just started the job so not reall a big deal but ery ANNNOYING none the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the designer of the printer software designed the USB interface. Clearly, they either intentionally or accidentally created the USB software to reset when power is detected.

I would report the problem back to whomever wrote the code. I agree that is an undesirable behavior and it could very likely be fixed easily in the code.

However, it is never safe to assume how ANY hardware will behave when "hot-plugged" (which is essentially what you did).  I would NEVER leave something like that plugged in when powering up the computer. As you have demonstrated, you never know exactly what will happen.

Comment: My bad lesson learnt. BY hot plugged you do mean plugging it in after I've already switched it on?

Comment: By "hot plug" I mean applying power after the device is already running. Either by physically plugging in the USB, or by powering-up the computer with the USB already plugged in.  From the POV of the printer, it makes no difference which way you do it. It is still "hot-plugging" either way.

Comment: Thanks. I dont think they'll care. At some point I'll probably attempt redesign it. Luckily for me it's a ramps board which is open source wahooo.